# Phase in Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I cannot understand what is meant by " Two pendulums are in phase" . What will happen if they are in phase and what does it mean?

Comment: Do you know the displacement relationship $x = A \cos(\omega t + \varphi)$? The phase of the oscillator is the argument in the $cos$-function.

Comment: Two people swinging on adjacent swings on a swingset are “in phase” when they stay next to each other, reaching the high point at the same time, etc. They are “180 degrees out of phase” when they are swinging oppositely, so that one is at the high point in one direction while the other  is at the high point in the other direction.